# older project loads on port 3000 despite i have deleted that project

Tags: reactjs, port

I have a problem since yesterday. I had a react project running on port 3000 (that project was run via Yarn)
I have deleted the project's folder as well as yarn, and since that when I try to run another react project, the server tries to run my deleted project and because it is not there so I got an error from Chrome that something went wrong while displaying the page.

[image]

I ran this command in order to terminate the process that occupied the port:

`netstat  -ano  |  findstr  <Port Number>`
`taskkill  /F  /PID  <Process Id>`

I even changed the port to another port but got exactly the same error from chrome.
[image]

I have no other solution to fix it. How can I fix the problem? :)

Comment: I dont think this has to do with your previous react project. The error itself says "out of memory", so there might be a problem with a memory leak or something in your current project?

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I solve the memory leak problem?

Comment: Well that cant really be simply answered. Try commenting out every function of your app and just display something like a 'Hello World' - if it works, you know something is wrong with your app (if not there must be another problem on your machine). Then you can either go on by continuing to activate feature by feature to see what causes it, or you use the developer tools to anaylze your app like described here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve.

1. Run this code `netstat -a -o -n`
2. You should get some active connections.
   [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6OOD.png)
3. Search for the key word 3000. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfa9e.png)
4. Locate the one with local address 127.0.0.1:3000 that has it's state as ESTABLISHED. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZONS.png)
5. Copy the PID and then enter this code `taskkill /F /PID ENTER_THE_PID_NUMBER_HERE`

Then you should get this response: [Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQD6E.png)